# Como posso resolver esse erro de NPE ao buscar dados em uma API?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

Estou querendo fazer uma pesquisa na API do GitHub usando Kotlin Coroutines em um thread diferente do principal, mas, ao receber os valores, está gerando este erro:

```
021-01-27 19:50:22.961 17831-17831/com.posart.githubinfo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.posart.githubinfo, PID: 17831
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.posart.githubinfo.network.UserNetwork.getFollowers()' on a null object reference
        at com.posart.githubinfo.views.details.DetailsFragment$onCreateView$1.onChanged(DetailsFragment.kt:47)
        at com.posart.githubinfo.views.details.DetailsFragment$onCreateView$1.onChanged(DetailsFragment.kt:17)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Não tenho certeza de como usar as corrotinas, mas acho que o problema não está exatamente no uso delas.  Acho que quando o fragmento obtém os dados da variável, a busca na API ainda não foi feita.
Colocarei aqui os arquivos que acho que podem estar associados ao erro:

### Repositório

```kotlin
class UserRepository {
    fun getUser(username: String): LiveData<UserNetwork> {
        val userResponse = MutableLiveData<UserNetwork>()

        GitHubApi().getUser(username).enqueue(object : Callback<UserNetwork> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserNetwork>, t: Throwable) {
                userResponse.value = null
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserNetwork>, response: Response<UserNetwork>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    userResponse.value = response.body()
                } else {
                    userResponse.value = null
                }
            }

        })

        return userResponse
    }

    fun getUserRepos(username: String): LiveData<List<RepoNetwork>> {
        val reposResponse = MutableLiveData<List<RepoNetwork>>()
        
        GitHubApi().getReposUser(username).enqueue(object : Callback<List<RepoNetwork>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<RepoNetwork>>, t: Throwable) {
                reposResponse.value = null
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<RepoNetwork>>,
                response: Response<List<RepoNetwork>>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    reposResponse.value = response.body()
                } else {
                    reposResponse.value = null
                }
            }
        })
        
        return reposResponse
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```kotlin
class DetailsViewModel(private val username: String) : ViewModel() {

    private val _user = MutableLiveData<UserNetwork>()
    val user: LiveData<UserNetwork>
        get() = _user

    private val _reposUser = MutableLiveData<List<RepoNetwork>>()
    val reposUser: LiveData<List<RepoNetwork>>
        get() = _reposUser

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                _user.postValue(UserRepository().getUser(username).value)
                _reposUser.postValue(UserRepository().getUserRepos(username).value)
            }
        }
    }

    class Factory(private val username: String) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(DetailsViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return DetailsViewModel(username) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable to construct viewmodel")
        }

    }

}
```

### Fragment

```kotlin
class DetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: DetailsViewModel

    private fun adapterOnClick(repository: RepoNetwork) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.data = Uri.parse(repository.html_url)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = DetailsFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater)

        val arguments =
            DetailsFragmentArgs.fromBundle(
                requireArguments()
            )

        val factory = DetailsViewModel.Factory(arguments.username)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(DetailsViewModel::class.java)

        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        viewModel.user.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            binding.followersAndFollowing.text = getString(
                R.string.followers_and_following,
                it.followers, it.following
            )
        })

        viewModel.reposUser.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            binding.recyclerViewList.adapter = ReposAdapter(it) {
                repository -> adapterOnClick(repository)
            }
        })

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: Aparentemente o código funciona, precisaria rodar o projeto no A.S para saber o ponto exato que dispara a exceção. Se tivesse no GitHub seria bem mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Eu já consegui consertar o bug. Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço Kotlin e não entendi todo o código. E não tenho certeza sobre o conceito de co-rotinas, tenho cá comigo que são códigos que passam o controle da execução de uma thread para outra de maneira manual através de uma API.

Parece estar acontecendo o que você falou, a variável estar nula porque está sendo acessada antes de ter sido atualizada pela callback, que normalmente como toda callback só será chamada ao final de uma longa operação (de rede por exemplo) de forma assíncrona em relação ao momento da chamada.

A resolução do problema portanto deve derivar dessa noção, por exemplo se você estiver em um dado trecho de código ou view chamando a operação assíncrona e tentando acessar o resultado logo na sequência (ou seja, de maneira síncrona) não irá conseguir.

Você deve acessar a variável num ponto em que ela tenha ficado disponível, seja dentro do callback, ou "postando" o código que usa essa variável na thread interessada (geralmente a thread principal, que cuida da exibição dos componentes gráficos), ou no caso dessa forma de co-rotina que eu descrevi passando o controle para a thread que faz uso dos dados, ou ainda usando algum recurso que facilite esse tratamento assíncrono, por exemplo uma possibilidade é pesquisar se existe algo no Kotlin parecido com as AsyncTasks que se usam no Java em Android. Na verdade esse código de co-rotinas/callbacks que você mostrou parece querer que você coloque o código que faz uso dos dados retornados da API dentro da própria callback, que no caso é `onResponse()` ou outra similar.

Na verdade deve ter uma forma de resolver no Kotlin que não estou sabendo qual é por não conhecer a linguagem. Mesmo assim a resposta certamente deve passar pelo entendimento de como funciona o ciclo de vida dos componentes em Android, como os fragments, e sua relação com a thread principal. Entendendo isso você mata a questão.

P.S.: Não entendi o que seria um UserRepository que acessa informações de rede (sendo que no nome consta só User) e sendo que um repositório, até onde sei, é um mecanismo para abstrair o acesso a dados, por exemplo de um banco de dados, de maneira geralmente síncrona, sem envolver callbacks.

Também tem que entender a questão do *binding* que está sendo feito, que é uma característica do Android com MVVM que eu não cheguei a acompanhar como funciona.